# Error in render v-for list objects key:value parent is null Vuejs3

Tags: vue.js

I have an error in vuejs3

i have this list
`items = ['alimentos', 'licores', 'varios']`

make object list

```
return {
    category: item,
    selected:false
}
});


// render withe v-for in template

<tr v-for="(category,idx) in categories" 
:key="category" 
@click="category.selected = !category selected">
<td>{{ idx + 1 }}</td>
<td class="text-start">{{ category.category }}</td>
<td class="text-success">

<i class="fa-solid fa-minus text-danger" v-if="category.selected"></i>
<i class="fa-solid fa-plus" v-else></i>
<td>
</tr>
```

// When I click on one of the items in the list, in the browser I get the error

```
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush.

ERROR
parent is null
insert@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-dom/dist/runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:171:5
mountElement@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4755:15
processElement@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4700:19
patch@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4628:25
patchBlockChildren@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4881:12
patchElement@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4816:25
processElement@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4702:19
patch@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4628:25
patchKeyedChildren@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.j
```

I have checked and I notice that the selected value of the item does change to true or false depending on the case,
but it does not show the change in the browser

If I change the values in the Vue inspector, there is no error and when showing the template the changed values are
shown
but if it is done with the template visible it throws the error I think the problem is with v-for

complete code component

```
<template>
    <div class="row mt-2">
        <h5 class="mt-2">ASISTENTES DE TOMA</h5>
        <div class="col bg-light">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-8 mt-2">
                    <input type="text" v-model="query" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar" @keyup="filterUsers">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condesed mi_table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>Username</th>
                                <th><i class="fas fa-cogs"></i></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr v-for="(user, idx) in all_teams" :key="user" @click="selectUser(user)">
                                <td class="text-center">{{ idx+1 }}</td>
                                <td class="text-start">{{ user.last_name }} {{ user.first_name }}</td>
                                <td class="text-start">{{ user.username }}</td>
                                <td class="text-success"><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 mt-2">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Usuarios Seleccionados</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">
                            <ul class="list-group text-start" v-for="user in selected_teams" :key="user.username">
                                <li class="list-group-item p-1" @click="selectUser(user,true)">
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-minus text-danger"></i>
                                    {{ user.last_name }} {{ user.first_name }}
                                    <small class="badge bg-light text-secondary border">{{ user.username }}</small>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mt-3">
                <div class="col text-start">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" @click="showView(2)">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-left"></i> Anterior
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-end">
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" @click="showView(4)">
                        Siguiente<i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: "TeamsTab",
    emits: ["showView"],
    props: {
        teams: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
        },
    },data(){
        return{
            query:"",
            all_teams: [],
            selected_teams: [],
        }
    },methods:{
        filterUsers(){
            // tomamos todos los usuarios
        const users = this.teams.map(item=>item);

            // quitamos los seleccionados
        this.all_teams = users.filter(
            item=>!this.selected_teams.includes(item)
         );

         // aplicamos el filtro
         if (this.query.length > 3){
             this.all_teams = this.all_teams.filter((item)=>{
                let params = this.query.toLowerCase();
                let target = item.first_name + ' ' + item.last_name;
                return target.toLowerCase().includes(params);
                }
             );
             return;
         }
         console.log('llgeamos a la fila');
        },
        selectUser(user, delete_usr=false){
            // agregamos un usuario a los seleccionados
           if (delete_usr) {
                this.selected_teams = this.selected_teams.filter(
                    item => item.username !== user.username
                );
                return;
            }
            this.selected_teams.push(user);
            this.filterUsers();
        },showView(view) {
            this.$emit("showView", view);
        },
    },
    mounted(){
        // cargar todos los usuarios asistentes
        this.filterUsers();
    },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error:

```
@click="category.selected = !category selected">
```

should be

```
@click="category.selected = !category.selected">
```

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, I copied the wrong code, the correct thing is as you indicate, but the problem still persists

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the v-if, but I don't understand why the problem, when I don't use v-if the error is not displayed.
I think that when making the change the variable remains null, throwing the error

posible solution

```
<template>
    <div class="row mt-2">
                    <h5 class="mt-2">PERSONALIZAR ITEMS TOMA</h5>
                    <div class="col bg-light">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6 mt-2">
                                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condesed mi_table">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>#</th>
                                            <th>Tipo</th>
                                            <th><i class="fas fa-cogs"></i></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr v-for="(category,idx) in all_categories" :key="category" @click="category.selected = !category.selected">
                                            <td>{{ idx + 1 }}</td>
                                            <td class="text-start">{{ category.category }}</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                <span :class="category.selected ? 'text-danger' : 'text-success'">
                                                    {{ category.selected ? 'Quitar' : 'Agregar'  }}
                                                </span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{{ all_categories.length + 1 }}</td>
                                            <td class="text-start">SELECCIONAR PRODUCTOS</td>
                                            <td><i class="fa-solid fa-search"></i></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6 mt-2">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h5 class="card-title">Items Seleccionados</h5>
                                        <p class="card-text">
                                        <ul class="list-group text-start" v-for="category in selected_categories" :key="category">
                                            <li class="list-group-item p-1"> 
                                                <i class="fa-solid fa-minus text-danger"></i>
                                                {{ category.category }}
                                                <ul v-for="item in category.items" :key="item">
                                                    <li> {{ item }} </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                               <div class="row mt-3">
                                <div class="col text-start">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" @click="showView(3)">
                                        <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-left"></i> Anterior
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col text-end">
                                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" @click="showView(5)">
                                        Siguiente<i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                    </button>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <br/>
                    </div>

                </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'ItemSelectionTab',
    emits: ['showView',],
    props: {
        categories: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            all_categories: [],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        showView(view) {
            this.$emit('showView', view);
        },showView(view) {
            this.$emit("showView", view);
        },filterCategories(){
            // obtenemos todas las categorias

            this.all_categories = this.categories.map((item)=>{
                return  item.type_product.split(";")[0];
            });
            // eliminamos los duplicados
            this.all_categories = [...new Set(this.all_categories)];

            this.all_categories = this.all_categories.map((item)=>{
                let items = this.categories.filter((category)=>{
                    return category.type_product.split(";")[0] == item;
                });

                items = items.map((item)=>{
                     return item.type_product.split(";")[1]
                });

                return {
                    category: item,
                    items: items,
                    selected: false,
                }
            });

            // quitamos las seleccionadas
            this.all_categories = this.all_categories.filter((item)=>{
                return !this.selected_categories.some((category)=>{
                    return category.category == item.category;
                });
            });
        },
    },mounted() {
        this.filterCategories();
    },computed:{
        selected_categories(){
            return this.all_categories.filter((item)=>{
                return item.selected;
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: The other answer clearly shows where is the problem.